# Perl Hash Comparison

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have two "different" files with the same kind of data i.e.

```
    KEY_gl Start_gl   End_gl
    1   114029  17
    2   284 1624
    3   1803    2942
    4   3070    3282
    5   3295    4422 

    KEY_gm Start_gm   End_gm
    1   115000  17
    2   284 1624
    3   1803    2942
    4   3070    3282
    5   3295    4422
```

I have saved these two different files in "hash" . The "Key" column is the key and the start and end are the values for these two different keys.

I have written a code to compare these two hashes and print out the "similar" and "non similar" keys from the files.

The Code is

```
my %hash_gl = ();
my %hash_gm = ();
open( my $fgl, "/home/gaurav/GMR/new_gl.txt" ) or die "Can't open the file";

while ( my $line_gl = <$fgl> ) {
  chomp $line_gl;
  my ( $key_gl, $start_gl, $end_gl ) = split( "\t", $line_gl );
  $hash_gl{$key_gl} = [ $start_gl, $end_gl ];
}

while ( my ( $key_gl, $val_gl ) = each %hash_gl ) {

  #print "$key_gl => @{$val_gl}\n";
}

open( my $fgm, "/home/gaurav/GMR/new_gm.txt" ) or die "Can't open the file";

while ( my $line_gm = <$fgm> ) {
  chomp $line_gm;
  my ( $key_gm, $start_gm, $end_gm ) = split( "\t", $line_gm );
  $hash_gm{$key_gm} = [ $start_gm, $end_gm ];
}

while ( my ( $key_gm, $val_gm ) = each %hash_gm ) {

  #print "$key_gm => @{$val_gm}\n";
}

for ( sort keys %hash_gl ) {
  unless ( exists $hash_gm{$_} ) {

    print "$_: not found in second hash\n";

    next;
  }

  if ( $hash_gm{$_} == $hash_gl{$_} ) {
    print "$_: values are equal\n";
  }  else {
    print "$_: values are not equal\n";
  }
}
```

Kindly tell the errors in this as I am not getting the desired output.Also , I am sorry that I am new to this forum so I am not able to do the editing correctly.

Comment: add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your script, re-run it and see what errors you get...

Comment: @FlyingFrog Sir.. I am not getting any errors after using use strict and use warnings also..Dats why I am confused.

Comment: What **is** your desired output?

Comment: If `1 2 3 4 5` are your keys, they exist in both hashes according to your example data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl Column comparison in two files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347456/perl-column-comparison-in-two-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to compare the *values*, say the start position, here's how I'd do it:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $in, '<', '1.txt' or die "$!\n";
open my $in2, '<', '2.txt' or die "$!\n";

my (%hash1, %hash2);

while (<$in>){
    chomp;
    next unless /^\s+/;
    my ($key, $start, $stop) = /\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/;
    $hash1{$key} = [$start, $stop];
}

while (<$in2>){
    chomp;
    next unless /^\s+/;
    my ($key, $start, $stop) = /\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/;
    $hash2{$key} = [$start, $stop];
}

for my $key (sort keys %hash1){
    if (@{$hash1{$key}}[0] == @{$hash2{$key}}[0]){
        print "start matches: file1 @{$hash1{$key}}[0]\tfile2 @{$hash2{$key}}[0]\n";
    }
    else {print "start doesn't match: file1 @{$hash1{$key}}[0]\t file2 @{$hash2{$key}}[0]\n"};
}
```

Comment: The OP is not comparing the keys at all. They are comparing the values (which are array refs) numerically and checking if each key of the first hash exists in the second hash.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your files, the two hashes look like this. I created the output using [Data::Dump'](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDump)s function `dd`.

```
my %hash_gl = (
  1      => [ 114029,     17 ],
  2      => [ 284,        1624 ],
  3      => [ 1803,       2942 ],
  4      => [ 3070,       3282 ],
  5      => [ 3295,       442 ],
  KEY_gl => [ "Start_gl", "End_gl" ],
);
my %hash_gm = (
  1      => [ 115000,     17 ],
  2      => [ 284,        1624 ],
  3      => [ 1803,       2942 ],
  4      => [ 3070,       3282 ],
  5      => [ 3295,       4422 ],
  KEY_gm => [ "Start_gm", "End_gm" ],
);
```

As you can see, the values are array refs. You put them in array refs when saying `$hash_gl{$key_gl} == [ $start_gl, $end_gl ];` (and the same for `gm`).

When you compare the two, you are using `==`, which [is used for numerical comparison](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators). If you print one of the `$hash_gm{$_}` values, you will get something like this:

```
ARRAY(0x3bb114)
```

That's because it's an array ref. You cannot compare those using `==`.

You now have two possibilities:

- you can do the comparison yourself; to do that, you need to go into the array ref and compare each value:

  ```
  if ( $hash_gm{$_}->[0] == $hash_gl{$_}->[0]
    && $hash_gm{$_}->[1] == $hash_gl{$_}->[1] )
  {
    print "$_: values are equal\n";
  }  else {
    print "$_: values are not equal\n";
  }
  ```
- you can install and use [Array::Utils](http://p3rl.org/Array%3a%3aUtils)

  ```
  use Array::Utils 'array_diff';
  # later...
  if (! array_diff( @{ $hash_gm{$_} }, @{ $hash_gl{$_} } )) {
    print "$_: values are equal\n";
  }  else {
    print "$_: values are not equal\n";
  }
  ```

I would go with the first solution as that is more readable because you do not need the dereferencing and the effort to install a module just to save half a line of code is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict; 
use feature 'say';

my %hash_gl = (
  1      => [ 114029,     17 ],
  2      => [ 284,        1624 ],
  3      => [ 1803,       2942 ],
  4      => [ 3070,       3282 ],
  5      => [ 3295,       442 ],
);

my %hash_gm = (
  1      => [ 115000,     17 ],
  2      => [ 284,        1624 ],
  3      => [ 1803,       2942 ],
  4      => [ 3070,       3282 ],
  5      => [ 3295,       4422 ],
);


sub check_hash_size {

my $hash_gl = shift;
my $hash_gm = shift;

if ((keys %$hash_gl) !=  (keys %$hash_gm)) {
 say "the hashes are 2 different sizes";
 }
 else
   {
   say "the hashes are the same size";  
   }
}

sub diag_hashes {

my $hash_gl = shift;
my $hash_gm = shift;

 for my $gl_key ( keys %$hash_gl ) {
   if (   (scalar @{$$hash_gl{$gl_key}}) !=  (scalar @{$$hash_gm{$gl_key}})  ) {
            say  "$gl_key entry arrays are different sizes";
   }
   else
      {
       say "arrays are the same size for key $gl_key";
      }           


   if (   ((scalar @{$$hash_gl{$gl_key}}) or (scalar @{$$hash_gm{$gl_key}})) > 2 ) {
            say  "$gl_key entry array exceeds 2 values";
   }

   if  ($$hash_gl{$gl_key}[0] eq $$hash_gm{$gl_key}[0]) { 
        say  "$gl_key start is the same in both hashes";  
        }
        else
            {
             say  "** key $gl_key start is different";
            }      

   if  ($$hash_gl{$gl_key}[1] eq $$hash_gm{$gl_key}[1]) { 
        print "$gl_key end is the same in both hashes","\n";  
        }
        else
            {
             say  "** key $gl_key end is different";     
            }  

 }


}


check_hash_size( \%hash_gl ,\%hash_gm); 
diag_hashes( \%hash_gl ,\%hash_gm);
```